# Android use DialogFragment in extends ListFragment class

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

i have `ReceiveListFragment` class. thats extends `ListFragment` and i want to use `DialogFragment` but i get this error :

```
Error:(200, 15) java: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String)
    method android.app.DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentTransaction,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual argument android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentTransaction by method invocation conversion)
    method android.app.DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual argument android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager by method invocation conversion)
```

i'm use and define like with this code:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        AddNoteDialogFragment dialog = new AddNoteDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(manager,"1");
```

My `DialogFragment` class is :

```
    public class AddNoteDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
            public AddNoteDialogFragment() {
            }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_sms_dialog,
                    container);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
            dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            return dialog;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem is that you are (unconsciously) mixing imports from the support library. You are supplying a `v4` fragment manager, while the parameter must be a native `FragmentManager`.

I had the problem vice versa: the param should be a `v4`, but I supplied a native `FragmentManager`. I had solved my issue by extending my class with `ActionBarActivity` in stead of `Activity` and I called `getSupportFragmentManager()` to supply a `v4` Fragment manager.